# Js for getting uploaded file name to php form not working in one server but working in other server

Tags: javascript, php

I have two forms which will upload two different csv files and perform some query over them. It runs well in my localhost and test site but not running in client's server.The form is in php and html and I am getting the uploaded file name using js

Here is the form code:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="upload-form" id="upload-form">

<input type="hidden" value="" name="filelist" id="filelist" />

<div class="form-group">

    <div class="panel panel-default" id="uploading-files-wrapper">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">MLS Research Data</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button ">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Select files...</span>
                    <input id="fileupload" class="fileupload" type="file" multiple="">
            </span>
            <br><br>
            <div id="progress" class="progress upload-progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 0%;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default" style="display: none;" id="uploaded-files-wrapper">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Uploaded files</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="uploaded_files" class="files"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
                <span style="padding-right: 5px">Import uploaded data</span>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Pyramis Actives Data
            
            
                
                    
                    Select files...
                        
                
                
                
                    
                
            
        

        
            
                Uploaded files
            
            
                
            
            
                
                    Import uploaded data

And here is the js for getting the filename and adding it to the form input

```
$(function () {

var $filelist = [];
var $active_filelist = [];

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'upload.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        $('#fileupload').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#fileupload.fileinput-button').addClass('disabled');
        data.submit();
    },
    done: function (e, data) {

        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $filelist.push(file.url);
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#uploaded_files');
        });

    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('.upload-progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }
}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled')
.bind('fileuploadstop', function (e) {

    var $_form = $('#fileupload').closest('form');
    $('#uploading-files-wrapper').slideUp('fast');
    $('#uploaded-files-wrapper').slideDown('fast');
    $('#filelist').val(JSON.stringify($filelist));

    $_form.append(
        $('<input type="hidden" name="import_data" value="1" />')
    );

});

$('#actives-form').on('submit', function () {
    var $submit_button = $('#active-files-wrapper').find('button');
    $submit_button.prop('disabled', true);
    $submit_button.html('please wait...');
});

    $('#actfileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'upload.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        $('#actfileupload').prop('disabled', true);
        $('.act-btn').addClass('disabled');
        data.submit();
    },
    done: function (e, data) {

        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $active_filelist.push(file.url);
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#actives_files');
        });

    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('.act-prog .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }
}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled')
.bind('fileuploadstop', function (e) {

    var $_form = $('#actfileupload').closest('form');
    $('#actives-files-wrapper').slideUp('fast');
    $('#active-files-wrapper').slideDown('fast');
    $('#active_filelist').val(JSON.stringify($active_filelist));

    $_form.append(
        $('<input type="hidden" name="import_data" value="1" />')
    );

});
```

});

This code is working in my localhost and another test site but not in my client's server, I tried many ways for 3 days but found no error, pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, the client's server had the upload folder 'files' write protected. So the json files were not getting to upload and no files were read. For all those who might face this same issue